# Proving $|f_n -f| \leq 2g$ in dominated convergence theorem prove

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading through the idea of proving the dominated convergence theorem with the bounded convergence theorem and I came across this inequality that seems obvious but I just want to confirm whether I am thinking about it the right way.

Assume that $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $|f_n|\leq g$

Since $-g \leq f_n \leq g$, monotonicity of the integral implies $-g \leq f \leq g$. With $-g \leq f_n \leq g$ and $-g \leq -f \leq g$, we obtain that $-2g \leq f_n+(-f) \leq 2g$. In other words, $|f_n-f|\leq 2g$.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't monotonicity of the integral, but rather just a consequence of how sequences converge. In general, if $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence bounded by $M$, then it's true that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \le M$$

In this case, fix an $x$ and apply this to the sequence $f_n(x)$, with upper bound $g(x)$; this establishes that $f(x) \le g(x)$.

An identical argument gives the reverse inequality, in which case your last sentence applies. You could also use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Could you lead me on how to use triangle inequality to prove this? I was stuck when I was trying to use it. Thanks

Comment: $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \le |f_n(x)| + |-f(x)| \le |f_n(x)| + |f(x)| \le M + M$